# get content of <p> id or class using PHP get

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I'm working with this [Script](http://shubhamtipstricks.com/2052/facebook-like-extract-url-data-using-jquery-php-and-ajax/) which allows to display url content within the meta tag "description". It uses php like this:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);
```

And then call it like this:

```
<label class="desc">
    <?php  echo @$tags['description']; ?>
</label>
```

How can I modify this to get content(plain text) of p, div, id, class instead of meta tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't modify this to get what you want, this function is for meta tags.

You could use [DOM API](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The content contained in p, div etc is not the same as meta-data. The meta data is the special stuff in the header that looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

That is the only data that is returned by the `get_meta_tags();` function.

Answer (score 0):

you could possibly get the file contents and then parse the content with xmlreader

$rContent = file("someHtmlFile.html");
$content  = join(" ", $rContent);
...

Here's the Link to XML Reader Documentation: http://de.php.net/manual/de/book.xmlreader.php

Greetz,
Lupo